# Is there a way to use sqlsrv.dll for PHP 7.2?

Tags: php, sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2

since I can't install an older version of php and there is no update from sqlsrv for PHP 7.2, is there a way to still use it? Everytime I try to install PHP 7.1.14 on my Windows Server 2012 R2, I get "The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly", but with PHP 7.2 everything is fine.

So how can I use sqlsrv in PHP 7.2?

Comment: You should use PDO http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php

Comment: As long as you have installed the proper Visual Studio Redistributable package(s) then you should be able to run almost any PHP version you want. I have Windows 7 x64 and am running the latest 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6, 7.0, 7.1, and 7.2 in both x86 and x64 at once using Apache and FCGI.

Comment: @JayBlanchard could you please tell me which extensions do I need to add in php.ini? Because I have added `php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_nts_x64` but it isn't shown in my phpinfo()

Comment: That information is in the docs.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus and that is my problem :/ I don't know which package is the proper one

Comment: @JayBlanchard in the docs it is just shown untill php 7.1

Comment: It should be the same.

Comment: @JayBlanchard yeah, then I guess PDO isn't working for php 7.2 too

Comment: You must have some other issue as several folks are successfully using PDO with SQL Server successfully on 7.2. Did you restart the server after you added the extension?

Comment: @JayBlanchard yeah, do I need any other driver or extension?

Comment: No other drivers or extensions are needed.

Comment: @Flacko If you look at http://windows.php.net/download then you will see `VC14` for the PHP 7.1.x downloads so [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) needs to be installed. Personally, I install all of the redistributable packages from 2005 to today.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus thank you for your answer, I have installed the package you referred me to but I still get the error.
Update: Was the wrong package. Now my PHP 7.1.14 is running :) thank you

Comment: @Flacko wrong package? Did I recommend the wrong redistributable or was it a x86 vs x64 issue?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus it was a x86 vs x64 issue.

But I still can't load the driver..

Comment: @Flacko It's possible you need to replace the dll using one of the latest from http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/sqlsrv/. Looks like 4.3.0 is the latest stable for VC14 so I would give it a shot. For IIS you need NTS and TS for Apache.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thank you really much, all fine now :)

Comment: You're welcome, would you be willing to accept it as an answer if I post it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of this writing, PHP 7.2 is built using VC15 and the latest stable release of the [sqlsrv driver](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/sqlsrv/) is 4.3.0 using VC14. However there is a sqlsrv 5.2.0rc1 available for VC15.

So, you have two options:

### Option 1: Install PHP 7.1

For this you will need the proper (x86/x64) version of [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145); also known as VC14. You can safely install both if you wish. I tend to install all of the redistributables from 2005 to today and have not run into issues.

If the sqlsrv driver prevents PHP from starting up then try downloading the correct VC14 version from the [pecl releases](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/sqlsrv/).

### Option 2: Install PHP 7.2

For this you will need the proper (x86/x64) version of [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads); also known as VC15.

If the sqlsrv driver prevents PHP from starting up then try downloading the correct VC15 version from the [pecl releases](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/sqlsrv/). Currently the latest is 5.2.0rc1 so it will most likely work properly but it is ill-advised to use it in a production setting.

***Important note***

NTS is for IIS servers and TS is for Apache. This is important when you go to download PHP or any of its drivers/extensions such as sqlsrv.

Comment: @Flacko You're welcome! Even though [Jay's comment about switching to PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48768158/is-there-a-way-to-use-sqlsrv-dll-for-php-7-2/48787979?noredirect=1#comment84537099_48787979) is an okay recommendation, it's not always feasible to simply switch technologies like that so I'm glad you got it working :)